# SystemJS: Fetch error when not specifying .js when importing

Tags: typescript, systemjs, commonjs

I'm using TypeScript with `module: "commonjs"` and I can't seem to import exported classes.

Let's say I've got an exported class Train, like so:

```
export class Train {}
```

Now I want to create an instance of that Train in another file, like so:

```
import { Train } from "./Train";

class Main {
    var train = new Train();
    console.log("Heck it, trainz!", train);
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/Train 404 (Not Found)

(index):10 Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:3000/Train
  Loading http://localhost:3000/App.js
  Loading App.js
    at fetch.js:37
    at <anonymous>
```

The `head` of my `index.html` looks like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        "defaultExtension": "js"
    });
    System.import('dist/App.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

If I'm adding .js to the import, the error goes away, but the `console.log` doesn't get called.
Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I figured it out. I called my init function using `window.onload` which wasn't being called anymore since `systemjs` takes care of everything now. Thanks for reading!